# Passing setState function as value through Context.Provider gives error

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I am trying to change the display of my React app by passing the setDisplay state-setting function as the value of Context.Provider. For some reason, I am unable to use the context that was passed down.

Here is my code for the higher up parent component:

```
import React from "react";
import { createContext, useState } from "react";

import Header from './Header'
import Display from './Display'

const DisplayContext = createContext(null);

export default function Game() {
    const [display, setDisplay] = useState('custom_background');
    const [isGameComplete, setIsGameComplete] = useState(false);

    return (
        <DisplayContext.Provider value={setDisplay}>
            {!display.includes('game_over') && <Header />}
            <Display display={display} />
        </DisplayContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

Here is my code for the further down child component:

```
import React from 'react'

import { useContext } from 'react';

const imagePresetFiles = import.meta.glob('../../assets/*.jpg')
console.log(imagePresetFiles)

export default function Preset({defaultBackground, backgrounds, setBackgrounds}) {
    const setDisplay = useContext(DisplayContext);

    console.log("Preset useContext", setDisplay)

    function handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        setDisplay('custom_difficulty_options');
    }

    function handleChange(event) {
        setBackgrounds([...backgrounds, event.target.value]);
    }

    function handleClear() {
        setBackgrounds([defaultBackground]);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <section>
                    <input type="file" multiple onChange={handleChange}/>
                    <div>
                        <section></section>
                        <section></section>
                    </div>
                    
                </section>
                <section>
                    <h2>NOTE:</h2>
                    <div>
                        <p>File must be in the .gif, .svg, .jpeg, or .png format</p>
                        <p>Multiple images added will be rotated each round</p> 
                    </div>
                    
                    <button onClick={handleClear}>
                            Clear Choices
                    </button>
                    <button>
                            Confirm Choices
                    </button>
                </section>
            </form>
            {backgrounds.map((background, index) => {
                return <img src={background} alt={background} key={index} />
            })}
        </div>
    )
}
```

I made sure that the specific displays inside of the Display component have the correct import path. I also made sure to place everything correctly, according to the React docs. I expected it to display the custom background display, and then allow me to be able to change it to the custom difficulty options display upon submitting the form. However, I got a blank screen, and an error:

Uncaught ReferenceError: DisplayContext is not defined

If you have any suggestions, please let me know!

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried importing `DisplayContext` by any chance?

Comment: `DisplayContext` is not imported at the child component, as well as not exported from the parent one (at least in the code added to your question)

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't know I still had to export and import the DisplayContext, I thought it would be readily available for use by any child component by default.